# How to create a color palette and export it for use in ggplot2 scale_fill_disteller

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, maps

I have a question. I need to create a color palette that I can use in ggplot2. I'm going to explain my problem. My idea is to create a sequential color palette to use for maps. Ideally, it should have many colors around 30 at least. This is because I need to represent a very long scale. Here are some color palettes that I saw on this page that might be similar to what I want and a new palette that would be ideal, or something similar.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Erufv.png)

Once this color palette is created, I need to use it in ggplot. That is specifically in scale_fill_distiller(palette="new palette created"). Previously I was using the "YlOrBr" palette, but it has few colors, I would need something similar to what I showed.
If the palette was sequential, but also included colors like red, orange, yellow, green, light blue, in that order, and about 6 types of these, then having about 36 would be perfect.

In the following image you can see how the graph looks when I use the "YlOrBr" scale, due to the lack of colors, many details of the map are lost.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBXm3.jpg)

And the ideal would be to see something like this (the following image was created by copying and pasting with different scales, something very manual just to interpret the idea).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZASR.png)

The code that would be generating these images would be the following:

```
ggplot(f,mapping=aes(x=lon,y=lat))+
  geom_contour_fill(aes(z=datos_variable,fill=stat(level)))+
  geom_contour(aes(z=datos_variable),color="black",size=0.2)+
  scale_fill_distiller(palette ="YlGnBu" ,direction = 1,super=ScaleDiscretised)+
  mi_mapa+
  coord_quickmap(xlim = range(f$lon),ylim=range(f$lat),expand = FALSE)+
  facet_wrap(~nombre_nivel,scales="free", ncol =length(nivel)) +
  labs(x="Longitud",y="Latitud",fill=nombre_escala,title = titulo_grafico)
```

and f is a dataframe similar to this, where the plots are made with facet_wrap() varying in the level tag.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96hzp.png)

Comment: The `scale_*_brewer`, `scale_*_distiller` and `scale_*_fermenter` functions are not meant to use your own palette. Use e.g. `scale_fill_stepsn` or `scale_fill_gradient`.

Comment: The [cols4all](https://github.com/mtennekes/cols4all) package has a pretty comprehensive list of palettes, a GUI, and functions for extracting values. If need be, you could probably concatenate multiple palettes together to get to 30 distinct colors.

Comment: Hi @Gerliebecario welcome to SO, please use `dput(f)` for pasting data instead of screenshots, that makes it easier to replicate your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need to use a custom palette, I either make the palette one-off because it is a few colors that I know I want, or a custom palette function, or the nifty `coloRampPalette`, which "fills in" colors if you provide some that you want in the palette.  If you want to just select values from a sequential palette, you can select [1:n] of that palette, all using scale_*_manual.

```
 library(ggplot2)

# palette function (hue palette, s is the starting hue)
hue_pal <- function(n,s=15) {
  hues = seq(s, s+360, length = n + 1)
  hcl(h = hues, l = 65, c = 100)[1:n]
}

# ramped palette starting with custom colors
jet_colors <- colorRampPalette(c("#00007F", "blue", "#007FFF", "cyan", "#7FFF7F", "yellow", "#FF7F00", "red", "#7F0000"))

# pre-made palette
cbPalette <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

df <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10),what = rep(letters[1:5],each=2))
num_colors <- length(unique(df$what))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y,color=what))+
  geom_point(size=5)+
  scale_color_manual(values = hue_pal(n=num_colors, s=0))
    
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y,color=what))+
  geom_point(size=5)+
  scale_color_manual(values = jet_colors(num_colors))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y,color=what))+
  geom_point(size=5)+
  scale_color_manual(values = cbPalette[1:num_colors])
```